# Finding a solution for dy/dx = x/y and dy/dx = -x/y

Tags: calculus

So after separating and integrating the solutions with the initial condition (0,0) I am getting are $y^2/2 = x^2/2$ and $y^2/2 = -x^2/2$.

I thought that dy/dx = x/y and dy/dx = -x/y are differential equations for hyperbolas, but when I try to graph them on wolfram alpha I get:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y^2%2F2+%3D+-x^2%2F2

and

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y^2%2F2+%3D+x^2%2F2

which are definitely not hyperbolas.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget the arbitrary constant when you take the indefinite integral! The actual equations you *should* get are

$$\frac{y^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$

and

$$\frac{y^2}{2}=-\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$

Graph those for various values of $C$ and you will get hyperbolas and circles (or their degenerates).

---

Here are the details. In the first equation, if $C>0$ then the graph is a right hyperbola centered at the origin, with the branches going up and down. If $C<0$ then the graph is a right hyperbola centered at the origin, with the branches going left and right. If $C=0$ then the graph is a "degenerate hyperbola", the lines $y=\pm x$ that intersect at a right angle at the origin.

In the second equation, if $C>0$ the graph is a circle centered at the origin. If $C=0$ the graph is a "degenerate circle," a single point located at the origin. If $C<0$ the graph is another "degenerate circle," the empty graph.

Comment: what about if C is 0?

Comment: @Quantitative: then you get a degenerate of a hyperbola, namely the pair of intersecting lines $y=\pm x$ (for the first equation) or of a circle, namely a point (the origin, for the second equation). Do you understand the concept of a degenerate curve or figure?